# MULTIPLE EIGEN VECTORS

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the system that I'm trying to solve:

$
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
   y'_1=&-2y_1&+5y_2&\\
     y'_2=&-y_1&-6y_2&
 \end{array} 
$

$
E_1= \left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
1\\
-(2+j)
 \end{array} \right]
$

$E_2= \left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
1\\
-(2-j)
 \end{array} \right] 
$

$\mathbf{y}_h=c_1\mathsf{e}^{(-4+i)t} \left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
1\\
-(2+j)
 \end{array} \right]
 +c_2\mathsf{e}^{(-4-i)t}\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
1\\
-(2-j)
 \end{array} \right]$

$\mathbf{y}_h= \mathsf{e}^{-4t}\left[
    \begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
    c_1 \cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)\\
   - 2c_1 \cos(t)-2c_2\sin(t)+c_2\cos(t)-c_1\sin(t)
     \end{array} \right] $

The book provides the correct answer as

$\mathbf{y}_h= \mathsf{e}^{-4t}\left[
    \begin{array}{rrrrrr}  
    c_1 \cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)\\
   \Big(- 2c_1 \cos(t)-2c_2\sin(t)+c_2\cos(t)-c_1\sin(t)\Big)/5
     \end{array} \right] $

Comment: Being an old member, it was inappropriate for you to post such opaque pictures. Use  MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions.

Comment: I tried but it didn’t work

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

The two eigenvectors for $-4+i$ are scalar multiples of each other. Multiply the second one by $2-i$ and you get the first one.

All nonzero scalar multiples of an eigenvector are also eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: So in that case I only have one eigenvector for -4+i and not two as the book states

Comment: @Diana Over an infinite field like the real or complex numbers, one eigenvector always yields infinitely many other eigenvectors: When $v$ is an eigenvector, the vector $\alpha v$ for any scalar $\alpha\neq 0$ is also an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue. However, the interesting number is the *dimension* of the eigenspace: that's not the number of eigenvectors, but the maximal number of *linearly independent* eigenvectors.

Comment: @Diana : You have a space of eigenvectors---an eigenspace---that is spanned by just one vector.

Comment: When we solve differential systems we need to take the normalized one. I totally understand that the vector has a span